# Create multiple hyperlink with shortcut using Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, hyperlink, menu, tags, nav

I am trying to create a menu using HTML and I saw a lecture on **Udemy** and in which the instructor just simply wrote

e.g `a*3` and automatically 3a tags were generated like this.

```
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href=""></a>
```

He did not mention how?

This is my code:

```
<nav class="menu">
        a*3
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the magic of [emmet](https://emmet.io/). For that to work in Sublime, you would need to install the emmet plugin for Sublime Text through package control.